# Making two divs in the same row?

Tags: css, html

How can I get two `div`s aligned in the same "row" on a website?

I have been working on [this page](http://harrisonbh.com/designsster2), and I have tried to get a menu that floats to the left side of the website and then the content to the side of that.

I have tried using this as the `div`'s CSS:

```
.menu
{
    width:25%;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    float:right;
    position:fixed;

}
.content
{
    width:70%;
    height:50%;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding: 25px;
    float:right;
}
```

The page is not displaying them side-by-side and floating, but instead how most website such as: http://www.exorithm.com/, where they have a sidebar and an area for content.
Can anyone help?

All my code: http://pastebin.com/KqYkrweE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have position:fixed on the menu.  If you use position fixed or absolute, it removes the element from the document flow, so float:right becomes irrelevant.

**Edit: Here is a better example of achieving the same result**

Also bear in mind that you are using percentages for width and then applying a pixel based padding.  This could lead to the elements becoming too wide for the page and displaying one below the other.

```
70% + 25% = 95% with 5% left over.
```

If the 5% is less than 50px (making the whole width 1000px) then your columns will total greater than the entire width.  A better approach would either be to use percentage based padding (not 100% sure how well this works) or to apply your padding, margins and borders to elements inside the floated columns, like so:

```
// CSS
.leftCol {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}

.rightCol {
    float:left;
    width:75%;
}

.content {
    padding:25px;
}

// Markup
<div class="leftCol">
    <div class="menu">
        Here is my menu
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rightCol">
    <div class="content">
        Here is my content
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit 2:**
If you want your menu to stay on screen as the user scrolls down, then position:fixed will do the job.  I looked at your page and it looks like you have a fixed width navigation of 206px.  Therefore your styles for the existing markup would be better off as something like:

```
// CSS
.menu {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:206px;
}

.content {
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 231px;
}
```

Comment: But when i fix it that all messes it up? Why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If you keep your markup as it was and use the styles under edit 2 this works fine (tested using Chrome's debugger bar to edit the styles and checked it over).  Do you have anything more specific than "it all messes up"?  How does it mess up and at what point?

Comment: I forgot the .content that you added. Haha thanks. I got it harrisonbh.com/designsster2/test2.html

Comment: If using the position fixed styles my markup is not necessary (so you can use .menu and .content instead of .leftCol and .rightCol).  The only purpose for my markup was to allow you to apply padding easily if you are floating the elements next to each other.  But as long as it's working, good job.

Comment: Thanks :) Is there anyway to make it seem more "alive" with JS? That you can think of?

Comment: Wow that's a pretty generic question.  Don't look for any easy fixes to make your page "pop" or "whiz" in javascript.  Here's one quick change that you can make (add into your css)  .menu a:hover {padding-left:10px;}

Comment: And for pity's sake give us some more contrast between the text and the background.  Either light text on a dark background or vice versa ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. You are floating right instead of left.
2. Your `.content` has a padding of 25px on each side, which means 50px overall. Since your `menu` is 25% and the `content` 70%, if your container is smaller than 1000px you run out of space.

Comment: So should it look like this?                                     .menu
{
 width:25%;
 height:auto;
 margin-bottom:2px;
 float:left; 
}
.content
{
 width:75%;
 height:50%;
 margin-bottom:2px;
 padding: 25px;
 float:left;
 

}

Comment: No. The opposite. you need less width, not more. Try 65% or a smaller padding on the sides